# Blueprint registration in Flask 1.0

Tags: python, flask

I try to register a Blueprint module in my main.py module, and every time become this error
"werkzeug.routing.BuildError:

Could not build url for endpoint 'posts.index'. Did you mean 'index' instead?"

Here is my code in main.py module:
'''

```
from app import app
from app import db
import view

from posts.blueprint import posts

app.register_blueprint(posts, url_prefix='/blog')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

'''
Here is my app.py :
'''

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request
from config import Configuration
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import render_template


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Configuration)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    name = 'Ivan'
    return render_template('index.html', n=name)
```

'''
And structure of the project itself on Picture[main.py and structure of the Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsMDj.jpg)

Where I've made a mistake?

Kind regards,
Michael

Comment: I'm really confused by the structure of your app. Why do you have `app.run()` _inside_ a blueprint?

Comment: Hello roganjosh, it's not a blueprint module, it is a main.py module, here I want just registrate my blueprint. I have next structure in project:
app.py
config.py
main.py
view.py
models.py

Here is my blueprint itself:
####################################################
from flask import Blueprint
from flask import render_template

posts = Blueprint('posts', __name__, template_folder='templates')

@posts.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('posts/index.html')
####################################################

Comment: main.py in my case it is just instance of app.py